# Translate string notation to recursive object pointer

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, error-handling

I want need to translate a notation (e.g. 'main:message:new') to the referred object property (resource[main][message][new]).

```
var notation = 'main:message:new';

var ressource = {
    message: { new: 'something' }
};

var splitKeys = function(keys, object) {
    var keys, pointer;
    pointer = object;
    keys = keys.split(':');
    for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        // here is the error
        if (pointer[keys[i]] === undefined) break;
        pointer = pointer[keys[i]];
    }
    return pointer;
};

console.log(splitKeys(notation, ressource));
```

As you see I got problems with the error handling. If there is a ressource notation which doesn't match a concrete ressource I want to return nothing. Unfortunately I always get an error thrown 'cannot read property undefined of undefined'...

Comment: Wrap `new` in quotes where it says `message: { new: 'something' }`. Access it with `resource.messsage["new"];`.

Comment: if (!pointer.hasOwnProperty([keys[i]])) {
    break;    
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first property name, called `main`, is not present in your resource object, thus your method will always return the entire object instead of the property value you are aiming at, which is `{ new: 'something' }`:

```
var splitKeys = function(keys, object) {
    var pointer = object;
    var parent = pointer;
    keys = keys.split(':').slice(1); // exclude `main`
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (pointer[keys[i]] === undefined) break;
        parent = pointer;
        pointer = pointer[keys[i]];
    }
    return parent;
};
```

This will return the `new` object, i.e., `{ new: 'something' }`. If you want to return  the property value instead, return `pointer` instead of `parent`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pBuEL/)**.

Comment: No offence, but using `var` will not override a parameter. It'll have no impact on the parameter, just like if you use `var` in the same function more than once for the same variable.

Comment: Again, no offence, but the `.hasOwnProperty` test isn't safe since you'll get an error if the property is defined with a `null` or `undefined` value (except for at the end of the traversal of course).

Comment: @user1689607: None taken :-), you are absolutely right, I've edited my answer.

Comment: We have just tested the ({'a':null}).hasOwnProperty('a'); expression, returns true in Chrome... And the same with undefined...

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't give my any error, so there may be some other issue.

But if you want to return nothing when the resource doesn't match, then you should use `return` instead of `break`.

```
var notation = 'main:message:new';

var ressource = {
    message: { new: 'something' }
};

var splitKeys = function(keys, object) {
    var keys, pointer;
    pointer = object;
    keys = keys.split(':');
    for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

        if (pointer[keys[i]] === undefined) 
            return null;

        pointer = pointer[keys[i]];
    }
    return pointer;
};

console.log(splitKeys(notation, ressource));
```

Also, if `pointer[keys[i]]` is `null`, the loop will continue, so you may want to change your test.

```
if (pointer[keys[i]] == null)
```

This will check for both `null` and `undefined`.